# I am trying to convert a website to an app and getting this error

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

This is my first app, I am trying to convert a website to app  in android studio. I am following this tutorial - [https://youtu.be/oy-0ss-n33g](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dihoz.jpg)  . But I am getting:

```
Cannot resolve symbol WebView
```

How can I solve this error?

[image]

Comment: please show your code source

Comment: Show your layout source

Comment: I believe you have to just import android.webkit.WebView to resolve that.

Comment: Either way, you could also auto import classes if you configure that in the Android Studio.

Comment: Build -> Rebuild Project in Android Studio. As last resort, use File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.

Comment: Build> clean project in android studio and Build > Rebuild project

Comment: I downvoted because: [Image of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode),  [No error description](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/), [No reseach](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to import `WebView` just add `import android.webkit.WebView` at the import section or alt + enter to auto-import the class

Answer (score 0):

Import this classes

```
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
```

And make sure the ID of the webview in your xml layout is the same as the one you are referring in java.